# Bootstrap - Input group button in List group Item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hey I'm kind of a new guy in bootstrap but I was wondering how to do something.

I've been trying and searching but I can't seem to do it. Does anyone know how to get these:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Sorry I can't quite provide an image right now but on the bootstrap website it is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) on Button Addons.

into a `list-group-item`? I want a button like that but on a list-group-item.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you import twitter bootstrap `bootstrap.min.css` and also make sure this has a parent element (somewhere up in it's tree) with either the class `.container` or `.container-fluid` ?

Comment: I'm not sure you understood. The code I have there is just so you know what I want to implement in a list-group-item. I want the list-group-item with a button just like that one.

Answer (score 6):

Just nest the `input-group` into the `list-group-item`, like this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
     <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you don't want to have the additional padding, you could do something like this:

1.) Add a special class to the `.list-group-item`:

```
<li class="list-group-item group-btn">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </li>
```

2.) Give it the following CSS:

```
li.group-btn {
  padding: 0;
}
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/TiR5p4m3WZ) (1. li is the basic example, the 2. li is without padding)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to work perfectly. Just wanted to point out the fact that you can also use a simple `p-0` thanks to the [Bootstrap Spacing Notations](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation) to replace the specific CSS class you made.